# Rotate both ImageView and Bitmap

Tags: android

I am trying to send image (both camera and gallery) to server. I cannot rotate image correctly. When I rotate image, it rotate properly and show rotated result in image view. But when I send to server, the image rotation is different from what I see in my android image view. Following is part of my code.

```
int rotation = (int) previewImage.getRotation();
        switch (rotation) {
            case 0:
                previewImage.setRotation(90.0f);
                break;
            case 90:
                previewImage.setRotation(180.0f);
                break;
            case 180:
                previewImage.setRotation(270.0f);
                break;
            case 270:
                previewImage.setRotation(0.0f);
                break;
            default:
        }
        Log.d("DEV", "DEGREE AFTER ROTATING --- " + previewImage.getRotation());
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.postRotate(previewImage.getRotation());
        imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap, 0, 0, imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight(), m, false);
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using `Front` or `Back` camera ?

Comment: @MD I am using only back camera.

Comment: You just need to rotate main img to 90 and send to server and set to `ImageView` By doing    `matrix.postRotate(90);`

Comment: @MD If I do so, my image will be always 90 degree rotation. I want my image to be same as I get in imageview.

Comment: Try to save that rotated image before sending it to server.. Once you successfully save that rotated image try to send that saved image path to the server.